# Receiving role when pressing on react

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I wrote this code to get the role when I click on a react, but even if I click on the react nothing happens, I also used console.log for debugging.
What do you think could be wrong?
I already have the reaction put on the server and I just put it in the code
This is the code

```
bot.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    if(reaction.emoji.name === "⛔") return;
    if(user === bot.user) return;

    let role = bot.guild.roles.cache.find("name", "Trusted");

    await user.roles.add(role.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the message you are listening for reactions is sent before the bot is online, the message will not be cached. Therefore, any reactions on that message will not call the `messageReactionAdd` event.
You can either fetch the message when the bot starts up:

```
channel.messages.fetch(<message-id>);
```

OR
You can enable partials when creating the client:

```
new Client({ partials: ['REACTION'] });
```

However, if you use partials, you must see if the reaction is a partial, then fetch the message first.

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
  if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
  console.log(`${reaction.message.author}'s message "${reaction.message.content}" gained a reaction!`);
});
```

Source: [Djs docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/topics/partials)